# My visitors %20 percent can't reachable to my web site

Tags: domain-name-system, ip

i have dedicated web server and also i hosting www.btgmaslak.com web site. I'm facing a problem about 1 days. My visitors about 20 percent can't reach my web site. I thing this problem occurs because of dns settings. Can you analyze my dns settings and give me suggestions ? thanks

http://www.intodns.com/btgmaslak.com

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the DNS servers you are referencing in your WHOIS record (ns1.vendabilisim.com and ns2.vendabilisim.com).  The domain "vendabilisim.com" shows both ns17.domaincontrol and ns18.domaincontrol as its DNS servers in WHOIS.

Now, the problem is that neither ns17.domaincontrol.com nor ns18.domaincontrol.com have records for ns1.vendabilisim.com or ns2.vendabilisim.com.

To resolve this, the person who manages vendabilisim.com will need to correct their DNS servers or you will need to find new DNS servers to host your domain and update your WHOIS record.

Edit: I'm guessing you are working on this, as WHOIS just updated to list ns07.domaincontrol.com and ns08.domaincontrol.com as the DNS servers for BTGMASLAK.COM.  Both seem to be responding normally now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I am managing vendabilisim.com at godaddy. Can you explain more ? My english isn't very good if you simple, i am plesead.